# Picasso: Unrecognized type of request for HTTP scheme

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am loading images synchronously to display notification once the image is loaded.

```
bitmap = picasso.load(imageUrl).get();
```

It was working fine but today I got an exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecognized type of request: Request{
http://www.fulbori.com/mp/resources/image/19/17/e.jpg}
       at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter$2.load(BitmapHunter.java:66)
       at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
       at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.get(RequestCreator.java:396)
       at com.jumbotail.app.utils.JtImageLoader.loadImageSync(JtImageLoader.java:397)
       at com.jumbotail.app.notifs.JumboGcmIntentService.readInboundIntent(JumboGcmIntentService.java:213)
       at com.jumbotail.app.notifs.JumboGcmIntentService.buildNotification(JumboGcmIntentService.java:273)
       at com.jumbotail.app.notifs.JumboGcmIntentService.onHandleIntent(JumboGcmIntentService.java:49)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I understand that this error is thrown by Picasso when no request handlers can handle the request.

Now, as per the `Uri` scheme of the request (which is `http`) [`canHandleRequest(Request data)`](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/NetworkRequestHandler.java#L43) method of [`NetworkRequestHandler`](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/NetworkRequestHandler.java#L43) should have returned `true`.

But all the request handlers returned `false` including `NetworkRequestHandler`. Thus, [`ERRORING_HANDLER`](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/BitmapHunter.java#L431) was returned by Picasso resulting into the exception : `IllegalStateException("Unrecognized type of request: " + request)`.

Is there any other explanation to this exception?

EDIT: I have also raised [an issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1493) in Picasso.

Comment: which OS version you got this ?

Comment: @Abdellah, almost all OS versions. whichever device got the notification.

Comment: I don't got it with Android API 23

Comment: This exception was one time. Never happened again.

Answer (score 14):

In particular I had this error because the URL I was getting, as the error mentions, is not a valid URL that a handler can use. In particular, the URL string had spaces before the "http", like:

`" http://example.com/image.jpg"`.

So I just had to call `trim()` on the url string, before loading it with Picasso, and worked great!

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a frustrating 30 minutes trying to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this if the path you pass Picasso is missing the hostname and scheme :-)